# pyunit testing with stubs in multiprocess code

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, multiprocessing, integration-testing, stub

I'm writing unit tests for a large python 2.7 project. There's a config file (called env) in this project that I'm trying to replace with a stub like so:

```
import env
import env_stub

#replace env with our stub.
env = env_stub
```

However, the project I'm working on calls some of its functions in separate processes (using `multiprocessing.Process`), and these separate processes end up using the original config file, rather than my stub.

Is there a way to ensure that these separate processes use the stub config file rather than the real config file?

Comment: Off-hand, this sounds like an [integration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). It's not testing something in isolation; it's testing a bunch of pieces together. My team has found that it's easy to let your integration tests get out of hand. I would just make sure I'm testing at the top tier of this application (so that it's testing some functionality in a way that the entire call stack gets hit) and actually let it use the config. Remember: testing is a tool you use wisely, not something you mechanically apply in every way possible.

Comment: @jpmc26, You're probably right that I'm using the wrong term for what I'm doing. I am writing an automated test of the top tier, if I understand you correctly. However, I want to swap out the config so that I can test against known settings.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the way I would solve that problem is to generate the config file at build time from a template file. Something like mustache is a good templating engine for such files, although I'm not sure how widely that is done.